# Automatically obtain the range of an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

Can any body tell me how to automatically obtain the range of an excel sheet .The data in the sheet varies every day and i am getting this data from database.
These date should be then updated in a pivot table that is present another sheet .
This should be done using c# code.

---

Update from answer posted:

My code is as follows..

```
Worksheet pivotWorkSheet = (Worksheet)Workbook.Sheets["Template"];

pivotWorkSheet.Activate();

Worksheet WorkSheet1 = (Worksheet)Workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = WorkSheet1.UsedRange;

if (xlRange != null)

{

 int nRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;

 PivotTable pivotMST=   (PivotTable)pivotWorkSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableMagazineSummeryStatus");
                int MSTResultSetRow = nRows;
                pivotMST.SourceData = "Sheet1!R1C1:R" + MSTResultSetRow + "C3";
                pivotMST.RefreshTable();
            }
```

---

My code is as follows..

```
Worksheet pivotWorkSheet = (Worksheet)Workbook.Sheets["Template"];

pivotWorkSheet.Activate();

Worksheet WorkSheet1 = (Worksheet)Workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = WorkSheet1.UsedRange;

if (xlRange != null)

{

 int nRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;

 PivotTable pivotMST=   (PivotTable)pivotWorkSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableMagazineSummeryStatus");
                int MSTResultSetRow = nRows;
                pivotMST.SourceData = "Sheet1!R1C1:R" + MSTResultSetRow + "C3";
                pivotMST.RefreshTable();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `Worksheet.UsedRange` property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks Dev..I am trying that only but its selecting the wrong row count.

Comment: Does your data starts in row 1:1? If don't row count is less then last row. If you are manipulating worksheet `UsedRange` may return a bigger range then actually used. Reopening workbook should fix it.